# Swagger: Converting Java LocalDateTime to Joda LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, jodatime, localdatetime

I converted Java LocalDatetime to Joda LocalDateTime all around my program. Now my Swagger request json is causing 400 response header errors.

How do I resolve for this in Swagger?

This was original working with JavaUtil LocalDatetime in Swagger request input.

```
{
   "dateOfService": "2021-08-20T17:01:16.637Z"
}
```

Now the conversion causes 400 response header errors.

Comment: I am wondering why one would downgrade from `java.time` to Joda Date-Time API having seen this notice at the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

Comment: hi @ArvindKumarAvinash thanks for letting us know, we are trying to fit with an old legacy project, appreciate you bringing it up, thanks

Comment: The input you have, `2021-08-20T17:01:16.637Z`, is not `LocalDateTime`. It is `ZonedDateTime` since it has timezone indicator (`Z`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After testing, You will have to convert it to UNIX Epoch time, even though the swagger predefined template shows it as date text.

Resource converter: https://www.unixtimestamp.com/

Example below:

```
{
   "dateOfService": 1633541458
}
```